# Using Curl To Send Info

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I have to use the Curl library to send a string to a morse code translator.(http://mattfedder.com/cgi-bin/morse.pl)
Then I have to take back the result and extract the translated code.
My prof didn't explain curl very well at all and I cannot find any clear examples.
I am not by any means asking for people to code it I just need sources to examples that may help. I apologize if these are blatantly easy to find I have put time into a search just none seemed relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl works with webpages/webservices etc.

Its library you can use to interact with web apps without writing all the code.
read this page.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html

(could not comment as i dont have 50 rep sorry)